# Clustering in different sized groups

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis

Anyone knows a method to group a set of points in different sized groups?

For example, I have 40 points and I would like to group them in 8 groups of

```
6,6,4,3,7,4,5,5
```

The points should be grouped in order to minimize the distance, but the most important criteria is the number of elements per group.

I have already tried the `Kmeans` method but with it, but I can't choose the groups size.

Comment: You should check out this article [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6984299), which addresses this exact problem ,using K-means as well. You should also consider asking this question in [cs](https://cs.stackexchange.com/), [cstheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/), and/or [datascience](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/).